# Need guidance in removing + in the result using REGEXP

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT ID,
    lower(LISTAGG(DISTINCT COL_A, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COL_A)) AS COL_1
FROM table_1
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
GROUP BY ID
```

| ID | COL_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | abc,+bda,+beach,relax |
| 23456 | unknown_user,+unknown_member,+others_to_denote |

When I run the above query, I'm getting results like mentioned above. I want the `+` symbol to be removed from the results. Is it possible to use REGEXP in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should do your cleaning prior to the LIST_AGG because currently you can have `abc` in your output many times:

```
SELECT 
    column1 AS ID
    ,LISTAGG(DISTINCT lower(column2), ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY lower(column2)) AS COL_1_a
    ,lower(LISTAGG(DISTINCT column2, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column2)) AS COL_1_b
    ,replace(COL_1_b,'+')
FROM VALUES 
    (12345, 'abc'),
    (12345, 'ABC'),
    (12345, '+ABC'),
    (12345, '+ABc'),
    (12345, '+AbC'),
    (12345, '+bda')
GROUP BY ID;
```

gives:

| ID | COL_1_A | COL_1_B | REPLACE(COL_1_B,'+') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | +abc,+bda,abc | +abc,+abc,+abc,+bda,abc,abc | abc,abc,abc,bda,abc,abc |

thus with a layer of "cleaning"

```
SELECT 
    ID
    ,LISTAGG(DISTINCT col2_cleaned, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY col2_cleaned) AS COL_1
FROM (    
    SELECT column1 as id,
        replace(lower(column2),'+') AS col2_cleaned
    FROM (
        VALUES 
            (12345, 'abc'),
            (12345, 'ABC'),
            (12345, '+ABC'),
            (12345, '+ABc'),
            (12345, '+AbC'),
            (12345, '+bda')
    )
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

more sensible results are produced:

| ID | COL_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | abc,bda |

### Other Cleaning points:

Do you really want all `+` tokens removed, sometimes it is just tokens at the beginning or the end that we want to remove, thus the replace can remove too much:

```
SELECT column1 as orig
    ,replace(lower(column1),'+') AS all_cleaned
    ,ltrim(lower(column1),'+') AS lt_cleaned
    ,rtrim(lower(column1),'+') AS rt_cleaned
    ,trim(lower(column1),'+') AS t_cleaned
FROM VALUES 
    ('abc'),
    ('ABC'),
    ('+A+BC'),
    ('+AB+c+'),
    ('+AbC+')
;
```

| ORIG | ALL_CLEANED | LT_CLEANED | RT_CLEANED | T_CLEANED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| ABC | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| +A+BC | abc | a+bc | +a+bc | a+bc |
| +AB+c+ | abc | ab+c+ | +ab+c | ab+c |
| +AbC+ | abc | abc+ | +abc | abc |

But you can also use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html) if you want to remove upto 2 `+` from the beginning but not more:

```
,regexp_replace(lower(column1), '\\+{1,2}','',1,1,'e')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to remove +, then you can use REPLACE

```
SELECT ID,COL_1, replace(col_1,'+') FROM VALUES 
('12345',  'abc,+bda,+beach,relax')
,('23456','unknown_user,+unknown_member,+others_to_denote') as tab(ID,COL_1)
```